# Getting "Please enter all fields error" no matter what is entered in register, using react-redux and jwt

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, jwt

I am using react-redux, axios, and JWT to create a registration system to a simple web app I built. No matter what is entered, I get a "Please enter all fields error". I have programmed other errors, and even when all input is valid I get the same one. I do not see any compilation error either in dev tools or in my terminal. This is my first try at authentication/registration.

```
This is my registerModal:

    class RegisterModal extends Component{

    state = {
        Modal: false,
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password:'',
        msg: null
    }
    static propTypes ={
        isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
        error: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        register: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        clearErrors: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
        const {error} = this.props;
        if(error !== prevProps.error){
            //reg error
            if(error.id === 'REGISTER_FAIL'){
                this.setState({msg: error.msg.msg})
            }else{
                this.setState({msg: null});
            }
        } 
    }
    toggle = () =>{
        this.props.clearErrors();
        this.setState({
            Modal: !this.state.Modal
        
        });
    }
    onChange = (e)=>{
        this.setState(
            {[e.target.name]: e.target.value}
            );
    }
    onSubmit = e =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const{name, email, password} = this.state;
        //create user object
        const newUser = {
            name,
            email,
            password
        };
        this.props.register(newUser);
        
    }

    render(){
        return(
        <div>
        <NavLink onClick = {this.toggle} href ="#" color = "danger">
            Register
            </NavLink>
        <Modal 
            isOpen={this.state.Modal}
            toggle={this.toggle} >
            <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Register</ModalHeader>  
            <ModalBody>
            {this.state.msg ? <Alert color = "danger">{this.state. msg}</Alert>: null}
                <Form onSubmit = {this.onSubmit}>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for ="name">Name</Label>
                        <Input
                            type = "text"
                            name= "name"
                            id = "name"
                            placeholder="Name"
                            onChange = {this.onChange}>
                        </Input>

                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for ="Email">Email </Label>
                        <Input
                            type = "email"
                            name= "email"
                            id = 'email'
                            placeholder="Enter email"
                            onChange = {this.onChange}>
                        </Input>

                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for ="Password">Password</Label>
                        <Input
                            type = "password"
                            name= "password"
                            id = "password"
                            placeholder="Password"
                            onChange = {this.onChange}>
                        </Input>

                    </FormGroup>
                        
                        <Button
                        color="success"
                        style={{marginTop:'2rem'}}
                        block>
            Register</Button>
                </Form>
            </ModalBody>
        </Modal>
        </div>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
    error: state.error
});
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {register, clearErrors})(RegisterModal);
```

This is in my auth.js file in routes folder:

```
//POST api/auth
//@desc Auth user

router.post('/', (req, res)=> {
   const { email, password } = req.body;

   //validation
   if(!email || !password){
       return res.status(400).json({msg: 'Please enter all fields'});
   }

   //Check for existing user
   User.findOne({email})
   .then(user =>{
       if(!user) return res.status(400).json({msg: 'User does not exists'})
      
    //Validate password
    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
    .then(isMatch =>{
        if(!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Invalid credentials'});
        jwt.sign(
            {id: user.id},
            config.get('jwtSecret'),
            {expiresIn: 3600},
            (err, token) => {
                if(err) throw err; 
                res.json({
                    token,
                    user: {
                        id: user.id,
                        name: user.name,
                        email: user.email
                    }
                });
            }
        )

    })
       
   });
});
```

authActions.js:

```
//check tokens and register user

export const loadUser = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    //user loading
    dispatch({type: USER_LOADING});

    axios.get('/api/auth/user', tokenConfig(getState))
        .then(res => dispatch({
            type: USER_LOADED,
            payload: res.data
        }))
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
            dispatch({
                type: AUTH_ERROR
            });
        });

}


export const register = ({name, email, password}) => dispatch =>{
    //headers
    const config = {
        header: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }

    //request body

    const body = JSON.stringify({name, email, password});
    axios.post('/api/users', body, config)
    .then(res => dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
        payload:res.data
    }))
    .catch(err=>{
        dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'REGISTER_FAIL'));
        dispatch({
            type: REGISTER_FAIL
        })
    })
}
//setup config /header and token
export const tokenConfig = getState => {
        //get token from local storage
        const token = getState().auth.token;

        //headers
        const config = {
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json"
            
            }
        }
    
        //if token add to headers
        if(token){
            config.headers['x-auth-token'] = token;}
    
    return config;

}
```

Please let me know if I should add anything.

Comment: Please provide the rest of the relevant code. Namely the `register()` function that you likely have in an "AuthActions" file. We need to see what the API call looks like.

Comment: I added the authActions file.

Comment: The route that you gave from auth.js is not for registering - it's for token validation. If you add the **register** (/api/users) route which you are hitting, I can help you further. Also, in your AuthActions.js `register` action, "`header`" in your `config` should be "`headers`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your registration route handles the request correctly, changing "`header`" to "`headers`" in the `config` you are passing into the `axios.post()` of your `register` action should solve it.